# Yogi Bear episode where he's cursed with hunger, and Boo Boo falls off a bridge?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, episode-identification, yogi-bear

I distinctly remember watching a rerun of an original cartoon episode matching this description.

Yogi Bear is cursed with insatiable hunger leaving Boo-boo. Boo Boo, eyes blinded by tears falls off a bridge?

When he realises his friend was hurt, he snaps out of the spell/curse.

I know at least one version of the cartoon has a witch character, but I can't find an episode matching this description.

Comment: [Yogi's Tummy Trouble](https://hanna-barberawiki.com/wiki/Yogi%27s_Tummy_Trouble)? Looks like a partial match.

Comment: @Laurel except it's not from the original cartoon, probably quite likely inspired by the original if I'm not imagining it

Comment: Who knew that Yogi Bear was SFF... I guess a pair of talking bears is "Fantasy"?

Comment: @FreeMan normally it's not, but the curse/magic is what tips this over.

Comment: Possibly handy, [The Curse of Tutti Frutti](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1652974/).

Answer (score 1):

I found the episode your looking for! It's called "Bearly Buddies" Yogi kicks out Boo Boo because he saw him give a cake to Ranger Smith. It was for Yogi's birthday. However, I remember they showed Boo Boo being rescued by an ambulance. I don't know if that part got cut or I'm just remembered it wrong. It was over 30 years ago when I first saw this on TV. The episode is available on Boomerang.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do any of the elements in the question match?  Is Yogi cursed with hunger?  Does Boo Boo fall off a bridge?